Android Facebook Login Error： Invalid Signature
Facebook Login Error
Facebook Login sdk version： 16.3.0   device：Android14 vivo x80

Invalid Signature
com.facebook.login.LoginManager.onActivityResult(LoginManager.kt:256)
com.facebook.login.LoginManager.registerCallback$lambda-0(LoginManager.kt:215)
com.facebook.login.LoginManager.$r8$lambda$pJs0X7lr0NZVFDkZnLW7STXSTPA(Unknown Source:0)
com.facebook.login.LoginManager$$ExternalSyntheticLambda1.onActivityResult(Unknown Source:4)
com.facebook.internal.CallbackManagerImpl.onActivityResult(CallbackManagerImpl.kt:45)


I follow every step in the facebook documents.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android/
most of the test devices is OK, only the Android14 vivo x80 no work.
Use the other facebook sdk version,17.0.0 15.0.0 14.0.0... also no work for my phone.
But it's ok when I change the sdk version to 11.3.0.
Any advices, Thank you in advance.

Did you manage to solve this issue?
I'm facing the same problem
